# javascript using global variables

Tags: javascript

can't seem to get this to work.

```
 var current_times = new Date();
 var future_times = new Date();

 function time(){
 current_times = current_times.setMinutes(current_times.getMinutes());
 future_times = future_times.setMinutes(future_times.getMinutes() + 1);     
 }
```

error im getting is: current_times.getMinutes is not a function

note sure this helps, but the time function is called from a function which is initiated on body load.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this code.  What browser are you using?  As I anticipated, I cannot reproduce the problem in Chrome.

Comment: 1. The specific code you pasted works. 2. Don't setMinute to getMinutes(). Why would you do that?!

Comment: post a complete non-working code sample.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `setMinutes` returns a number, not a `Date` object.

The function will work the first time you call it, but on the second call `current_times` and `future_times` will be numbers, and hence won't have the `getMinutes` function. Since `setMinutes()` modifies the `Date` object instead of producing a new one, the solution is to not reassign your variables.

---

Furthermore, if I understand your intentions correctly, your code can be simplified to:

```
var current_times, future_times = new Date();

function time() {
    current_times = new Date();
    future_times.setMinutes(current_times.getMinutes() + 1);
}
```

Comment: good catch, I was thinking that maybe he was declaring those variables in a namespace and nullifying their globalness.

Answer (score 0):

the code is right
but as Box9 typed code

you must assign variables inside the function
to be like that'

```
function time() {
     var current_times = new Date();
     var future_times = new Date();

     current_times = current_times.setMinutes(current_times.getMinutes());
     future_times = future_times.setMinutes(future_times.getMinutes() + 1);     

     document.write(current_times);
     document.write("<br>"+future_times);
}
```